# How to convert inch value to a valid dpi

Tags: graphics, android

I have an image that is displayed in both browser and android app. When the user clicks on the image in browser android app will get the location of the click in terms of "inch". 
Left 0.002 , top 0.0.52

Any help on how to convert the received "inch" to convert into valid value for my android app?

I got suggestion that for IPhone 96 is to multiplied which did not work from Android.

Android: image scale type is matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert various value types using

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html

So if you want to convert inches to pixels, so that you could use pixels to position/draw things on the screen, try somethig like this:

```
Resources r = context.getResources();
float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_IN, 0.002, r.getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: what value should i have in my dimension folder for  r.getDisplayMetrics() to give me value

Comment: not sure if I understand your question. basically you don't need to add anything.

Comment: ok, so u meant to use default Display metrics values, will give a try and update.

Comment: for (left) 5.8125 inch converted value was 1858.7794 and for (top) 5.7 converted value was 1877.1674... which is not correct